# How to add placeholder kinda thing in ruby select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

*1)* Is there any way I can add a placeholder/first option  as "(Select City)"

```
<%= f.select :city_id, options_for_select(@cities.collect { |city|
    [city.name.titleize, city.id] }, 1), {}, { id: 'cities_select'} %>
```

*2)* Can I use collection_select or say please if anyone can transform it into a collection_select tag *(with @cities array not City model)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `prompt` or `include_blank: 'My Placeholder` options in the `select` method http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

```
f.select :city_id, options_for_select(@cities.collect { |city|
[city.name.titleize, city.id] }, 1), {include_blank: 'Select Something'}, { id: 'cities_select'}
```

Comment: f.select :city_id, options_for_select(@cities.collect { |city|
[city.name.titleize, city.id] }), {include_blank: 'Select Something'}, { id: 'cities_select'}   *** this worked thanks